# How to force https for the whole site

Tags: ssl, symfony4

I have seen that to force https I can use annotations, php, yaml or xml configuration, but this is per controller.

My site define routes using annotations, so, is there a way to set https scheme for the whole site? I don't want to edit source code and go through all over the controllers to add https as scheme.

I have found some little information but regarding Symfony 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a `routes.yaml` file in the `config` project folder, just add the following (*for each controller global resource folder if you have more than one*):

```
#index:
#    path: /
#    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\DefaultController::index' }
_controllers:
    resource: ../src/YourControllerFolder/
    type: annotation
    schemes:  "https" <--- this line
```

From the docs:

> This configuration will load annotations from any controller stored
>   inside the src/Controller/ directory and even from its subdirectories.
>   So if your application defines lots of controllers, it's perfectly ok
>   to reorganize them into subdirectorie

[Routing Configuration Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#routing-configuration)

Comment: As I said, I use annotations only in controllers. So, the only content of my routes.yaml is: index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index

Comment: @jstuardo You mentioned the default framework routing configuration, so as mentioned in the referenced link (_as best pratices_) just define/configure each controller resource (_like in my edited example, commenting out the default config_), to then continue to define each route in each controller using annotation as you said. I hope you will got the point :-)

Comment: Yest.. but my idea is not to add manually each controller to routes.yaml file... I am sure there is an easier way. Maybe using .htaccess file.

Comment: @jstuardo Again, you don't need to manually add each controller to main `routes.yaml`, with this configuration you will load annotations from any controller stored inside the `src/YourControllerFolder/` directory and even from its subdirectorie and there you can also define some global parameter, as you need to do for `https` schemes parameter (_but also to define some global controller options if you need it_). Please, read the referenced link and the docs more carefully, is clearly state there what I mean and it is exactly what you need.